# How do you disable Pocket on Firefox 38 and up with GPO?

Tags: firefox, group-policy

Firefox announced that their new version would be integrated with Pocket. I would like to disable this for my users in my domain.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the record I think this is a horrible decision by Mozilla (especially since they had been working on their own alternative called *Reading List*), compounded by the fact that it's enabled by default for everyone.

Firefox has no native Group Policy support as you might know. There are various free/paid add-ons and solutions to add such support, such as [GPO For Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gpo-for-firefox/), [FirefoxADM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefoxadm/), [Firefox + Group Policy Object](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firefoxplusgpo/), [FrontMotion Firefox Community Edition](http://www.frontmotion.com/fmfirefoxce/) and [PolicyPak for Firefox](http://www.policypak.com/products/manage-firefox-with-group-policy.html). I cannot personally vouch for any of them however since I've never tried them (IE or Chrome is the way to go in my opinion if ADM/ADMX support is required).

Regardless of which one you decide to go with, what you need to do is set **browser.pocket.enabled** to **false** for all your users:

[image: 1]

Comment: In _Mozilla Firefox_ 51-53 (and maybe several earlier versions), the pref is named `extensions.pocket.enabled`.

Comment: source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/remove-pocket-button-firefox

Comment: Agreed - letting a private company buy bloatware and adware into an essential browser (now pretty much the only technical competitor to Chromium) used by millions of people is absolutely fucking outrageous.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out CCK2. It is easy to setup and distribute within your domain. I currently use it to control our Firefox deployments with great success. You can use it to control pretty much any aspect of Firefox.