# How to disable Pocket in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I've set `extensions.pocket.enabled` to `false` in `about:config`. [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/) is still displayed as enabled in `about:support` > `Extensions`:

```
Pocket | 1.0.5 | true | firefox@getpocket.com
```

---

[a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/923072/how-do-you-disable-pocket-on-firefox-38-and-up-with-gpo) (the accepted answer is outdated and and about group policy disabling method)

Comment: @Ramhound: He is asking about group policy.

Comment: Remove the `firefox@getpocket.com.xpi` file from firefox installation directory. It's in `browser\features`

Answer (score 1):

To completely disable Pocket out of your Mozilla Firefox browser, you should go to about:config and then search for:

```
extensions.pocket.enabled
```

and then set it to false.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-pocket-firefox

Unfortunately, there's no way to remove Pocket out of Firefox permanently as it has become a part of the browser.

Comment: There is one way to really remove Pocket from Firefox - Could always try editing the source code & compiling yourself. So maybe "there's no easy way"

Comment: `browser.pocket.enabled` preference no longer exists.

Comment: @Xen2050 then is there a know way (like a patch) to remove pocket from source ?

Comment: @carpinchosaurio I don't know, but there are (or at least used to be) other browsers built from Firefox that don't have some of those types of "features", Pale Moon might've been one IIR, but a web search would be more revealing

Comment: @user598527 apparently it's called `extensions.pocket.enabled` now, searching for just pocket may be helpful in the future. Or see the marked duplicate Q, that's where I read the new name (in a comment)